# PHP: Is there a way to avoid having to use the fully qualified class name when checking if an object is an instance of a class?

Tags: php

I understand that `is_a` accepts a string as the second argument but I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the following using `instanceof`:

```
use App\Module;
class Foo {
    function Bar($obj) {
        return ($obj instanceof Module);
    }
}
```

or

```
use App\Module;
class Foo {
    function Bar($obj) {
        return ($obj instanceof Module::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that a class `App\Module` exists, and given:

```
use App\Module;

class Foo 
{
    public function bar($obj) 
    {
        return $obj instanceof Module::class;
    }
}
```

this works fine:

```
use App\Module;

$module = new Module();

$foo = new Foo();

var_dump($foo->bar($module)); // true
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class